# Is there a Python 2 equivalent of Javascripts confirm() command?

Tags: javascript, python

Short version is simply the question.

Longer version:
I am learning Javascript via Codecademy, while trying to relearn Python 2 at the same time. I just finished the Choose Your Own Adventure Story.

In the code below, I can figure out how to easily adjust everything to Python 2 besides the code except the confirm command in Line 2.

```
// Check if the user is ready to play!
confirm("It's gametime!");
var age = prompt("What's your age");
if (age < 13)
{
console.log("You're really young, but go play");
}
else
{
    console.log("You're old enough. Start playing");
}
console.log("You are at a Justin Bieber concert, and you hear this lyric 'Lace my shoes off, start racing.'");
console.log("Suddenly, Bieber stops and says, 'Who wants to race me?'");
var userAnswer = prompt("Do you want to race Bieber on stage?");
if (userAnswer === "yes")
{
    console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!");
}
else
{
    console.log("Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'");
}
var feedback = prompt("Rate this game from 1-10");
if (feedback > 8)
{
    console.log("Thank you! We should race at the next concert!");
}
else
{
    console.log("I'll keep practicing coding and racing.");
}
```

I'd appreciate any help. Many thanks.

Comment: So why are you ignoring the return value of the `confirm()` call? Why use it at all if you cannot cancel? Python has no such dialog, you can just create a function that asks for `yes` or `no`, see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658) for help with such functions.

Comment: If you want a GUI dialog you can use `tkinter`'s `askyesno()` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you're attempting to capture input from a user at the command line you would use the [raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) function:

```
age = raw_input("What's your age?\n")
```